# Assessing BAPoster’s boxes as TikZ coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, baposter

I am using BAPoster and want to connect two boxes with a line. As BAPoster is uses TikZ to create and position its boxes, I expect that the boxes have TikZ identifiers and therefore can be used as TikZ coordinates. However, I fail to find how I can address them.

Here is a minimal example with a non-working naïve approach:

```
\documentclass[a0paper]{baposter}

% To avoid errors:
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=uk]{english}

\begin{document}
\begin{poster}{textborder=roundedsmall}{}{}{}{}

\headerbox{Bananas}{name=bananas, column=1, span=1}{Bananas\\Bananas}
\headerbox{Apples }{name=apples,  column=2, span=1}{Apples\\Apples}

% I want something like this, but working:
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \draw (observations) to (references);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

This throws the following error:

```
! Package pgf Error: No shape named bananas is known.
```

How can I make this work?

Comment: Not sure if it's possible with `baposter` commands, but you could use `tikzmark`.

Comment: @Ignasi: As far as I see it, `tikzmark` only allows me to mark certain points in the text, but not the boxes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

May be I'm wrong, but after some diving inside `baposter.cls` I think that `baposter` boxes are not defined as nodes.  Each box is built based on several `coordinates` which are remembered and can be used to connect boxes.

These coordinates are defined with syntax `coordinate(\baposter@box@name nw)` where `\baposter@box@name` is the name assigned to each box with `name=...`. It took me some time to discover that previous syntax doesn't consider the white space and the real name is `namenw`.

I've found coordinates: `...nw`, `...se`, `...tnw`, `...tne`, `...outer nw`, `...outer ne`, `...outer se`, `...outer tnw` and `...outer tne`. They correspond to following points over the box:

[image]

[image]

I don't know what's the difference between  `outer` and `nonaouter` coordinates.

In any case, you can use them to draw lines connecting baposter boxes.

```
\documentclass[a0paper]{baposter}

% To avoid errors:
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=uk]{english}

\begin{document}
\begin{poster}{textborder=roundedsmall}{}{}{}{}

\headerbox{Bananas}{name=bananas, column=1, span=1}{Bananas\\Bananas}
\headerbox{Apples}{name=apples,  column=2, span=1}{Apples\\Apples}

\draw[thick, blue] (bananasnw) to[out=180, in=-90] (applesse);
\path (bananasnw)|-(bananasse) coordinate[pos=.75] (aux1);
\path (applesnw)|-(applesse) coordinate[pos=.75] (aux2);

\draw[thick, green] (aux1) to[out=270, in=-90] (aux2);


%\begin{scope}[every node/.style={inner sep=3pt}]
%\filldraw[red] (bananasnw) circle (2pt) node[above left] {namenw};
%\filldraw[red] (bananasse) circle (2pt) node[below left] {namese};
%
%\filldraw[blue] (bananastnw) circle (2pt) node[above left] {nametnw};
%\filldraw[blue] (bananastne) circle (2pt) node[above left] {nametne};
%
%\filldraw[green] (applesouter nw) circle (2pt) node[above right] {nametouter nw};
%\filldraw[green] (applesouter ne) circle (2pt) node[above left] {nametouter ne};
%\filldraw[green] (applesouter se) circle (2pt) node[below left] {nametouter se};
%
%\filldraw[cyan] (applesouter tnw) circle (2pt) node[above right] {nametouter tnw};
%\filldraw[cyan] (applesouter tne) circle (2pt) node[above left] {nametouter tne};
%\end{scope}

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use `\subnode` or `\pgfmark` from the `Tikzmark` package. This facilitates placing marks associated with particular `posterbox` elements, such as certain words or letters of text. I should note that I was unable to get either `\tikzmark[<drawing command>]{<name>}` or `\tikzmark{<name>}{<coordinate>}` to work.

Marks can also be directed to the `posterbox` coordinates identified in @Ignasi's excellent answer, by shifting the placement of the marks using the usual `TikZ` syntax.

In the MWE, I changed `headerbox` to `posterbox`, as the former was deprecated, although it still functions. I also added a more complete specification of the `baposter` options.

This is the code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{baposter}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
\begin{poster}{
        grid=false,
        columns=2, % how many columns 1-6
        colspacing=5.0mm, % spacing between the columns
        headerheight=0cm, % the height of the header for the title
        background=none, %user or none or plain
        eyecatcher=false, %turn left logo on/off
        %posterbox options
        headerborder=closed, % see the baposter manual for the rest
        borderColor=darkgray,
        headershape=rectangle,
        headershade=plain,
        headerColorOne=darkgray,
        textborder=rectangle,
        boxshade=plain,
        boxColorOne=white,
        headerFontColor=white,
        textfont=\tiny,
        headerfont=\normalsize\bfseries,
        linewidth=1pt}
    {}{\textcolor{white}{dummy}}{}{} % Eyecatcher, title, author, right logo. There must be at least one entry.

\begin{posterbox}[name=bananas, column=0, span=1]{\subnode{C}{B}anana\pgfmark{Y}}{
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
            Banana\subnode{A}{s} \\ Apples\pgfmark{Y}
        \end{tabular}}
\end{posterbox}
\begin{posterbox}[name=apples, column=1, span=1]{Apples\pgfmark{Z}}{
        \begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
            \subnode{B}{D}urian \\ Mangostee\subnode{D}{n}
        \end{tabular}}
\end{posterbox} 

\draw[orange,thick,->] ([shift={(-2ex,-2ex)}]pic cs:A) to[out=-355, in=-200] ([shift={(-3ex,-2ex)}]pic cs:B);
\draw[magenta,thick,->] ([shift={(-4ex,-2ex)}]pic cs:C) to[out=230, in=-135] ([shift={(4ex,-4ex)}]pic cs:D);
\draw[blue,thick,->] ([shift={(0ex,5.5ex)}]pic cs:Y) to[out=-340, in=160] ([shift={(-3ex,0.5ex)}]pic cs:Z);

\end{poster}
\end{document}
```

This is the output:[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need to access the boxes themselves, not their content. (Also, regarding the complete poster specifications: I removed them on purpose to acquire a minimal example. Don’t worry; I won’t use a eye-cancer colours.)